# Typescript. How to specify a type of a subset of object literal properties?

Tags: typescript

Specify a type as in 'has property of this type' but may have other properties that we don't care about.

I have the two interfaces:

```js
interface IForm {
 form: {
   name: string;
   email: string;
   picture: File | null;
 }
}
```

and a sub interface

```js
interface IUpload {
 form {
   picture: File | null;
 }
}
```

How would I specify in the IUpload interface that the `form` variable should not be that exactly, but rather just have this field, so that the `extends` relationship would work in this case. `IForm extends IUpload`?

Sorry if I didn't formulate the question correctly.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're good as it is, I just completed your code and corrected a few typos :)
`IForm` can extend `IUpload` as it has the picture property.

```js
interface IForm extends IUpload {
    form: {
        name: string;
        email: string;
        picture: File | null;
    }
}

export interface IUpload {
    form:
    {
        picture: File | null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you:

```
interface IForm {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  picture: File | null;
}
```

Then in your IUpload:

```
interface IUpload extends Partial<IForm> {
  other: things;
}
```